# Retrieve data from database for template which is not related to domain objects

Tags: php, model-view-controller

In a regular MVC application you have your mappers which map and set data in your domain objects but what do you do when you have to retrieve a lot of data which would not go under the category of a domain object?

I am making this application and the client now wants to be able to edit the data on a few pages of the website (headings, text colour, bullet points...). The data is stored in the database but it would not really go under the category "domain/business object" in my eyes so what is the best way to retrieve this sort of data?

I do not want to be in one of my view methods and doing direct database queries from there to retrieve the data for the template. I would like to abstract it but putting it into domain objects and using mappers would seem wrong.

Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: You description of the problem seems confusing. I don't see how you make the leap from "I need to edit a document" to "I need to call SQL queries from UI logic". What exactly is the unsolvable dilema that you face?

Comment: Basically I have data stored in the database related to content on a page, the text in headings, colour of that text, text in bullet points etc and I want to retrieve that data on certain pages. I do not want to create a domain object and mapper for this job because they are for the model layer. Should I just directly do the query from the view, get back an array and then bind the data to the template?

Comment: You will have to give an example of what queries you need to perform from the view, because I don't see the source of your problem.